# How to extend a class from a CSS file in Sass?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I have a style library with the general styling for my project. This library is packed into one `library.css` file. In this library, I have a class `a`.

In one of my `scss` stylesheets I'd like to extend this calss `a` from `library.css`:

```
@import 'library.css';

.b {
 @extend .a
}
```

When I do this, I'm told that class `a` was not found in `library.css`.

Is there any way to extend a class from a CSS stylesheet?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you add an `@import` at-rule to your Sass code, you need to be careful what you wish to achieve. `@import` is actually valid CSS, so Sass needs to evaluate and figure out your intentions here. Sass extends the CSS `@import` rule and does not recreate it. According to [the documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import):

> @import takes a filename to import. By default, it looks for a Sass file to import directly, but there are a few circumstances under which it will compile to a CSS @import rule:
>
> - **If the file's extension is .css.**
> - If the filename begins with http://.
> - If the filename is a url().
> - If the @import has any media queries.

As a result, if you put the .css extension after the filename in an `@import` at-rule, Sass will just output this line of valid CSS code. You can test this by removing your `@extend` directive, which will make your code compile. You will see that the entire output file is this:

```
@import 'library.css';
```

Sass is not going to follow that CSS file and make it's contents available to the `@extend` directive.

What you could do is remove the file extension from your `@import` at-rule.

```
@import 'library';

.b {
 @extend .a
}
```

However, this will actually output the entire contents of the file library.css into your CSS file that this Sass file compiles to, which I am assuming is not your goal.

To fix that, you could create a partial Sass file that contains placeholder selectors.

```
%a {
  color: red;
}
```

The good thing about placeholder selectors is that they have no output of their own. According to [the documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#placeholder_selectors_foo):

> On their own, without any use of @extend, rulesets that use placeholder selectors will not be rendered to CSS.

Their importance and usefulness is detailed [on this page](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#placeholders).

Import the partial Sass file in your Sass stylesheet and use the `@extend` directive like this:

```
.b {
  @extend %a;
}
```

And to make sure your library.css file is consistent, convert it into Sass, import the same partial file on top of it containing your placeholder selectors and simply use the `@extend` directive inside `.a` selector as well.

```
@import 'placeholders';

.a {
    @extend %a;
}
```