# animate.css imports fail for webpack

Tags: reactjs, sass, animate.css, webpack-5

**Describe the bug** Module build fails

**Expected behavior** No errors to be yielded and project compiled successfully

**Screenshots**

**`Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: The target selector was not found.
Use "@extend .animated !optional" to avoid this error.

╷
10 │         @extend .animated;
│         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵`**

**Desktop (please complete the following information):**

- OS: MacOS
- Browser chrome,FireFox

**Additional context** Migrating my project to webpack5 from v3 of webpack. I encounter this above specific error while executing the project via webpack. The build fails and yields these errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I made a mistake on the import of the animate library :

```
@import "~animate.css/animate.css";
```

instead of

```
@import "~animate.css/animate";
```

In the first case, the css `@import` is used instead of the sass `@import` which causes the bug.

More explanations in this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48681729/1659617